# How to perform unit test on Azure Devops when required AWS glue libraries not available on Azure devops

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure-devops, pytest, aws-glue

I have a few modules having Python functions which are using aws glue libraries and pyspark and I am using them on the AWS glue console by mentioning them in libraries and importing them in the aws glue console environment where I can find glueContext and DynamicFrame to run them ... but I need to perform unit tests on them. I have tested locally by creating environment using official docker image amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 and performing automated tests through nox and pytest . Now I want to run same tests on Azure Devops.

Not from Devops background so no idea for using Azure Devops. If i can use official docker image of aws-glue-lib amazon/aws-glue-libs:glue_libs_4.0.0_image_01 to create a environment for unit testing then I think solution can be found but not idea how to approach for the same. Also on git repository of aws-glue-lib if we can clone in our testing environment on Azure Devops before testing that may also work.